# Homogeneous function of degree $-1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

If I have a bounded and homogeneous function of degree $-1$, can I conclude that it goes to $0$ pointwise at infinity, isn't it?

Comment: Defined on which set?

Comment: In a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is homogeneous of degree $-1$ then
$$
f(t\,x)=\frac1t\,f(x),\quad t>0,\quad x\ne0.
$$
Choose $t=1/|x|$ to get
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{|x|}f\Bigl(\frac{x}{|x|}\Bigr).
$$
Let $M$ be an uper bound for $f$. Then
$$
|f(x)|\le\frac{M}{|x|},\quad x\ne0.
$$